# How to pass in kubernetes config into a docker run command?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, configuration

I want to run a command on a docker container that has kubectl installed but not yet configured.

On my local machine, I have my kubectl authenticated and configured to communicate with a kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud.

If I run the command:

```
docker run mycontainerimage kubectl get pods
```

I'll get the response:

```
invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided
```

How can I pass my kubernetes credentials/configuration into the docker image running on my local machine? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can [mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only) your config file with -v into the container

```
docker run -v ~/.kube/config:/kube/config ...
```

and set the environment variable [KUBECONFIG](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#the-kubeconfig-environment-variable)

```
docker run -v ~/.kube/config:/kube/config --env KUBECONFIG=/kube/config ...
```

now every kubectl call should use the mounted config file.

Comment: The issue I'm encountering with this command is that my .kube/config files has references to a bunch of files (certificates and executables) on my local machines since I'm using gcloud to handle authentication. As a result, I'm getting no such files or directories errors.

Comment: Thanks! if you're getting permission denied due to SElinux, try with `-Z`, e.g. `-v ${KUBECONFIG}:/tmp/kubeconfig:Z -e KUBECONFIG=/tmp/kubeconfig`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Kubectl  Configuration/authentification depends on many resources and symlinks in the environment to connect to the cluster.

I think the best and the most secured solution is to configure a VPN that provides secure remote SSH access in the cluster and connect to the API-Server Remotely.

Kubernetes support [SocketXP](https://www.socketxp.com/docs/guide/kubernetes-pod-remote-ssh-access.html), here is a step-by-step guide about how to [Configure local kubectl to access remote Kubernetes cluster](https://dev.to/gvelrajan/configure-local-kubectl-to-remote-access-kubernetes-cluster-2g81).

Comment: this is wrong. one literally just needs one file and one environment variable pointing to that file.